# Can you see clearly _why_ $x$ and $h$ are linearly related in a triangle?

Tags: geometry, volume

Consider a triangle with $x \in (0,6)$ and $h \in (0, 8)$:

**Question:** Often times in questions related to volumes I have leveraged the property that $x$ and $h$ are *linearly dependent* to get the relationship $h = 8 - \frac{4}{3}x$. How can we see this visually?

(Edit: Something a little more than similar triangles, to intuitively see how $x$ and $h$ move together in a linear way)

[image]

Comment: Can you see why this is true using similar triangles?

Comment: @TobyMak Yes, but I was more interested in some sort of catesian intuition - by drawing a plane on the figure or something similar

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes that's right (I am already familiar with similar triangles), I was more interested in seeing how $x$ and $h$ move together in a linear way, if that makes sense?

Comment: Intuitively it's just because the sides of the triangle are straight. If you construct a $h$-axis as being a vertical axis (like $y$-axis) with $h=0$ at the base of the triangle, and an $X$-axis as being the horizontal axis with $X=0$ being the vertical axis of symmetry of the triangle in your diagram, then the fact that the right (say) side of the triangle is straight means that its equation as a line in the $X$-$h$ plane is of the form $X=ah+b$. Note that the left side is similarly also going to have $X$ be a linear function of $h$, and from this we can deduce that $x$ will be linear in $h$.

Comment: @user523384 Put all the thing into cartesian coordinates and see slope of the triangle edge, which is on the right, is $-8/3$ and for the left edge the slope is $8/3$, so if the top vertex has coordinates $(a,0)$ then the lines are $x_l-a=3/8 y$ and $x_r-a=-3/8 y$, Now, $x=x_r-x_l=-3/4 y$, but $y=h-8$ hence the desired result.

Comment: It's possible to write down a general formula for a Euclidean similarity in Cartesian coordinates. Is that what you are asking about?

Answer (score 2):

That's because the sides are straight lines.

Answer (score 0):

Linear algebra could help visualising why $ h$ and $x $ are linearly dependent as you can assume left adjacent sides as $X'-H'$ axis with angle $\color{green}{\theta}$, which are transformed from rectangular coordinate $X-H$ axis by using matrix $$ \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\frac{1}{sin\theta}\end{bmatrix}$$ and hence in oblique coordination we have $$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\h'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\\\frac{h}{sin\theta}\end{bmatrix}$$ where $\theta $ is the angle between left adjacent sides of triangle.Now the third side of triangle, which is a segment of line $ \color{green}{(} $all points on line are linearly dependent $\color{green}{)}$, can be expressed as linear combination of $x'$and $h'$ and hence of $x$ and $h$.